# Not Found node-pty - ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-pty

I am developing a simple Desktop app where I need to embed an interactive terminal like `Terminal` in VSCode. But I get the following errors constantly, while the node.pty and all dependencies are installed. Additionally, Unable to load preload script: while the address to the preload.js script is correct.

- Node: v18.17.1
- ElectronJS: 27.0.3
- node-pty": "^1.0.0",
- "xterm": "^5.3.0"
- macOS Sonoma M2

1. `innerError Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/pty.node'`
2. `Uncaught Error: Loading non-context-aware native module in renderer:`
3. `Unable to load preload script: /Users/user/folder/folder/folder/preload.js`

I tried running it with `npm start`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.